# How to create inline div fixed to the left?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display 2  inline but it's not working as I want.
Here is my code :

```
<div id="left-menu">
    <div id="map-menu" class="test">
      <nav class="menu_content">
        <ul>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
            <li>Link</li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="icon-menu" class="test">
      <button id="button_menu" class="js-menu menu" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

css :

```
#left-menu{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map-menu{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}

#icon-menu{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}

.test{
  display:inline-block;
}

#button_menu{

}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  background: 0;
  float: left;
  margin: 2rem;
  height: 2.7rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

The display I want is the Links fixed to the middle left of the page. And directly right from the links the button.
What I have instead is the button and the links are fixed to the middle left of the page (which is good) but the button is on the links instead of being next to them.
I tried all the display and poition attributes but I couldn't get what I want. 
I know the solution must be simple but I'm really struggling with that. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Take a look of this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1jy8rqL4/) and leave your comments.

Comment: The glyph icon should be on the same line than the list, on the right (but not on the right side of the page, it should be next the list)

Comment: How about this? https://jsfiddle.net/1jy8rqL4/1/ updated.

Comment: That's perfect Pangloss thx a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used to much `position:fixed` in your example. Ideally you only need it once on the very outside container element, and use `transform` to make it vertically centered in the screen.

To make the menu and icon in the same line, you can just use `display:inline-block`.

```
#left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Along with some small tweaks, see the following updated snippet.

```css
#left-menu {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#map-menu, #icon-menu {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#map-menu ul {
  margin: 0;
}
.menu {
  background: transparent;
  margin: 2rem;
  height: 2.7rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  z-index: 2;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="left-menu">
  <div id="map-menu" class="test">
    <nav class="menu_content">
      <ul>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
        <li>Link</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div id="icon-menu" class="test">
    <button id="button_menu" class="js-menu menu" type="button">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You fixed the button's position to be 50% away from top you can do as well for the left side.

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rqtwvjfn/)

```
#icon-menu{
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left:40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using fixed and you are applying the same property to both of the #map_menu and #icon_menu. This is what is causing them to overlap. If you want them next to each other wrap them in the same div such as:

```
<div id="map-menu" class="test">
            <button id="button_menu" class="js-menu menu" type="button">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></span>
            </button>

            <nav class="menu_content">
                <ul>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                    <li>Link</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div
```

And apply the following css (removed some stuff):

```
#left-menu{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#map-menu{
position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}

#icon-menu{
position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
}

#button_menu{
    display: inline-block;
}
.menu_content{
    display: inline-block;
}


.menu {

  float: left;
  margin: 2rem;
  height: 2.7rem;
  width: 3.5rem;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

Comment: with this code, the button is on the left even when you change the order in the HTML. (It should be on the left)